# MySQL Select ALL from Left Join

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

This query does not work. I want all the results from a `LEFT JOIN` where something is something. This is my exact code:

```
SELECT * FROM `swarovski_zones` WHERE `siteid`='200'
LEFT JOIN `trafficviews` ON `swarovski`.`id`=`trafficviews`.`adid`
```

`swarovski_zones` table is **siteid 200**

`trafficviews` table is **adid 200**

The 200 is the linking variable between the tables. I want everything from both tables where the ID is 200.

Comment: Apart from the sintatic error you've got a semantic error. You're only getting `everything from left table where id is 200`. You need an outer join to get `everything from both tables where the ID is 200`

Comment: If the id **may not** exist in `swarovski_zones` and it's possible for it to only exist in `trafficviews` you should unaccept my answer and accept @MostyMostacho's who has the correct on for that scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query doesn't work because the syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
select
from
join
on
where
group by
having
order by
limit
```

Giving you:

```
select *
  from `swarovski_zones`
  left join `trafficviews`
    on `swarovski`.`id` = `trafficviews`.`adid`
 where `siteid` = '200'
```

Also is `siteid` meant to be a string and not an integer?

I'm probably going to regret providing the list above...

`Limit`! I forgot `Limit`; the full syntax list is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Thanks this works, however in my table I see two fields "id" they are the same auto generated primary key IDs for both tables.. so the rows have them in.. will this affect it - I have two ID columns?

Comment: Thw `JOIN` and `ON` are part of the `FROM` clause. Much like the `AND` and `OR` that may appear in `WHERE` clause (or in `HAVING` or ...)

Comment: As I said @ypercube; I'm going to regret providing the list :-). I seemed fairly pointless to miss out `join` when that is what the OP had a problem with.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, you see two IDs because you've selected everything from both tables. If you don't want to select everything you're going to have to start naming individual columns unfortunately. If you want to rename some columns you still have to explicitly state column names but you can do something like `select id as tid from ...`

Comment: Ahh, yes the as command would be brilliant. Much appreciated.

Comment: Note this won't give `everything from both tables where the ID is 200`. A full outer join is required.

Comment: @MostyMostacho; yes assuming that the ID doesn't exist in the first table you're correct. If it does it's a lot of extra work for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that elements in your right table (trafficviews) might not have a correspondant row in your left table (swarovski_zones). So the left join will get all elements from the left and might leave out some elements from the right.

To solve this, you need an outer join. Your problem is that MySQL does not support outer joins :) This is solved in the following general way:

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM a RIGHT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE a.id IS NULL;
```

Applied to your question this should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM swarovski_zones s
LEFT JOIN trafficviews ON s.id = t.adid
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM swarovski_zones s
RIGHT JOIN trafficviews ON s.id = t.adid WHERE s.id IS NULL
WHERE s.siteid = 200 or t.adid = 200
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

User **full outer join**

```
SELECT * FROM `swarovski_zones` WHERE `siteid`='200'
FULL OUTER JOIN `trafficviews` ON `swarovski`.`id`=`trafficviews`.`adid`
```

Comment: There is no `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL. That is not the problem with the query.

Comment: At no point in that article is `full outer join` written in a select statement.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo: Not "Use FULL OUTER JOIN". Your answer could be "Simulate FULL OUTER JOIN" (and possibly an example of how to).